# What are the effects and scalings of the possible offhand configurations for the Temple Guardian?

Tags: sacred-2

I've encountered a bunch of almost decade-old posts mentioning that TG gets different combat bonuses from having different combat arts *selected*, which show up as different models for his offhand cannon.

Are these bonuses explained or documented in the game somewhere, and do said bonuses scale with any skills or equipment (such as his battery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's only one offhand configuration with passive benefits:

Having Battle Extension selected on the skill bar provides a 50% chance to play an attack animation that hits twice. The shoulder arm uses the same weapon stats as the normal hit and can apply on-hit effects independently.

The only other skill with a passive effect seems to be Dedicated Blow which prevents you from using battery-based ranged attacks by turning the gun-arm into a mace without any upside.